# Substring match using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like a regular expression to match the leading 4 characters of a string in .NET.

To be more specific, I'm using the `substring` method to search for the 1st occurrence of a piece of string and the 4 characters that precede it.

Let's say I have a string like this:

..In my code, this is what I do

```
string s = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk.ABCD kglog doplsjood"
string x = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("ABCD"))
```

...This is what I get, `x = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk.ABCD"` what I'm looking for is how to get the 5 characters before ABCD in the above string (hjdk.) so that my final string is "hjdk.ABCD".

I could probably use a `char Array` then the reverse function that comes with it so that I can read my string backward but I believe a regex will work faster hence in my question title I stressed 'using regular expression'.

Comment: You question is not clear.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Post some code what you want in your result .

Comment: Ok..let's say I have a string like this string s = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk.ABCD kglog doplsjood"..In my code, this is what I do string x = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("ABCD"))...This is what I get, x = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk.ABCD" what I'm looking for is how to get the 5 characters before ABCD in the above string (hjdk.) so that my final string is "hjdk.ABCD". I hope it's clearer now. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting a little tired seeing posts like this here. The author is asking the community to write code for him without showing any efforts of his own. Sure it may be good to get a quick reply and have a few lines of code to copy but what is actually learnt from it. I know this has been said many times before but new users should be educated!

Comment: @UNNELNGOUMANDJOKA you might want to add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not a RegEx but if you're already using C# then you could add a ExtensionMethod to String to do this for you.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Preceeds(this string s, string word)
    {
        string response = s;

        int pos2 = s.IndexOf(word);
        int pos1 = s.Substring(0, pos2).LastIndexOf(" ");

        if (pos1 != -1 && pos2 != -1 && (pos2 >= pos1))
        {
            response = s.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + word.Length);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this.

```
x = s.Preceeds("ABCD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear however maybe you need something like below.

```
string text = "abcdefghijklmn";

string myString = (text.Length > 3)? text.Substring(text.Length - 4, 4): text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want [String.StartsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)

```
if(myString.StartsWith("ABCD"))
    return "Found!";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "asdf";

(?<=asdf)\w+$
```

This will Match the words after "asdf" till the end of line. You may have to change the end of line depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
.{4}asdf
```

Will match asdf and the four preceding characters.  It will not match asdf occuring as part of the first 3 characters in a word.

It might be better for you to use

```
.{0,4}asdf
```

But it depends on how you want edge cases to behave.

```
String      |First match of .{4}asdf |First match of .{0,4}asdf
123asdf     | *No match*             | 123asdf
12345asdf   | 2345asdf               | 2345asdf
asdfasdf    | asdfasdf               | asdfasdf
123asdfasdf | asdfasdf               | 123asdf
```

Substring based solutions are faster than regexp based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works also and decided to share it with the rest of the forum. Thank you for assisting. This is what I did:

string s = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk.ABCD kglog doplsjood";

string x = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf("ABCD"));

//This gives me x = "adgstuoppdnmudio hjdk." Then I do the below to get the last 5 characters

string lastChars = x.Substring(x.Length-Math.Min(5,x.Length));

//This gives me lastChars = "hjdk."

Comment: It's true that (unlike what my question suggested) this solution doesn't use regular expression but I decided to post it anyway just in case there are people out there who like me struggle a bit with regular expressions